# Как в браузере открыть и редактировать документ Word?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, ms-word

Хочу написать приложение на ASP.NET MVC и передать во View документ Word и/или Excel так, чтобы его можно было редактировать в браузере и получать отредактированный документ обратно.

Как мне это сделать? Какие технологии нужно использовать?

Answer (score 2):

Средств браузера недостаточно. Используйте существующие web-компоненты, которые имеют редактор для word-документов. Точно есть у DevExpress и Telerik. Возможно в сети есть бесплатные Java-script редакторы.

Либо напишите сами, используя Open Xml SDK и JavaScript:

[Как создать документ используя Open XML Format SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd440953%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Разве что написать свой Word на JavaScript или взять у гугл докс (если это возможно). А если имеется ввиду MS Office то гарантированного способа нету разве что юзер сначала делает Export(Download) документа, у себя редактирует (не обязательно в браузере), а потом делает Import документа на сервер.